# Kmeans label returns NaN cluster

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, cluster-analysis, k-means

I imported ~340,000 customers records through Redshift SQL into Jupyter Notebook, and tried to use Kmeans to cluster these customers into 4 segments based on the revenue and the number of transactions they made for a certain period of time. But Kmeans labelled ~269 thousand of them (78.9%) as NaN cluster; 267k/340k were labeled as NaN when I tried 10 segments. When I applied the same codes to a small subset -- 692 out of 1000 were labeled as NaN cluster.

Sorry that I am not able to provide a group of simulated data for your trials, as Kmeans worked totally fine with data directly imported with Excel.

#### Following are my codes FYI -

```
import pandas as pd 

import numpy as np

from scipy import stats

from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans, vq


f1_df = df_df['total_revenue_m3_from_personal_investment'].values

f2_df = df_df['total_trades_m3'].values 

df_tr = np.array(list(zip(f1_df, f2_df)))
```

#### try 4 clusters

```
kmeans_4 = KMeans(n_clusters=4)

details_4 = kmeans_4.fit(df_tr)

labels_4 = details_4.predict(df_tr)

centroids_4 = details_4.cluster_centers_

idx,_ = vq(df_tr, centroids_4)
```

Comment: Maybe you have NaN values in your data?

Comment: Hi the values are as normal as the others. I just figured it out - it was because I took subset of the users dataframe, and thus needed to reset_index. Anony thx anyway!